# Yii CGridView filter, modify data before filtering

Tags: php, yii

One field in CGridView is a 'quota' field with a value in bytes. To make it human-readable, I'm using CFormatter:

```
'columns' => array(
    ...
    array(
        'name'  => 'quota',
        'value' => function($data) {
            return Yii::app()->format->formatSize($data->quota);
        },
    ),
),
```

Now I'd like to filter data in this column by megabytes. I've modified the search() method in model like this:

```
$criteria->compare('(quota / 1024 / 1024)',$this->quota,true);
```

but I don't like how it looks like. Is there a normal workaround?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
array(
    'name'  => 'quota',
    'value' => function($data) {
        return Yii::app()->format->formatSize($data->quota);
    },
),
```

You could simply do:

```
'quota:size',
```

---

Now, to answer your question, using the compare function is wrong, as it adds a "WHERE" clause to the SQL query. You are looking to do a sort instead using the `order` property:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->order = "quota DESC";
```

---

EDIT (after your comment):

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->addCondition('quota > '.intval($this->quota)*1024*1024);
```

Comment: Thank you for 'quota:size' hint, it's very simple. According to the second part, I'm not trying to order. In the database the 'quota' is being saved in bytes, which is not a human-readable format. In CGridView I'm displaying it in megabytes (now like `quota:size`) and want filter to handle megabytes also. So if user sees columns with values like 50, 50, 70, 100, 200 he could put in the filter **>70** instead of **>73400320**